# Express can't match the URL when using Angular http.post, but match when using CURL (only with POST method)

Tags: angular, express, rest

I have a strange issue, Express can match a post URL when I use curl, but not when I use the http.post from my Angular service.

If I use CURL, it works :

curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/add-type-client -d '{"nom":"sdf"}'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

Express match the URL

But In my angular service I have :

```
let url:string = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/add-type-client";

const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'} ;

let observable : Observable<any> = this.http.post(url ,  {"nom":"John"} , {'headers':headers});

return observable;
```

Express can't find the URL, and returns a 404.

Here is the code from my nodejs script :

```
var app = express(); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) 
app.use(express.json());

// Not executed with Angular but executed when I use CURL 
app.post("/add-type-client" , typeClients.create);


app.use(function(req , res , next) {
    console.log("app.use next");
    next(createError(404)); });
}
```

Any ideas ? By the way, If i use GET instead of POST, it works.

Thanks

Comment: Your "Angular service code“ doesn't look like an Angular Service at all

Comment: Try to add app.use(express.cors())

Comment: And remove that custom header from your angular code..

Comment: Share `typeClients.create` and @MikeOne might be up to something with CORS, but first make sure you get a CORS error before blindly adding it ;)

Comment: app.use(express.cors())  works thanks. Actually I knew I add to add it, I thought I did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to add:

```
app.use(express.cors())
```